# Can we get a notification when someone edits a post we upvoted or downvoted so that we can retract or change the vote?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I came across some posts (answers as well as questions) that I had downvoted due to their low quality; however, later the OP updated them, and now they are good ones. But my downvote was still there, and I even forgot that I ever voted for them.

Isn't it better if we get a notification when someone edits the question we voted for so that we can retract or change the vote?
It doesn't make sense to keep questions downvoted after improvements.

I find it more relevant with ID questions; when someone new posts the ID questions, they mostly have very little information. Most people don't understand that origin, year of release, etc. are important parameters. Later, when someone explains, the OP improves their questions.

Comment: I wish we had that feature but we don't.

Comment: Related: [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/162011) and [Option to be notified when a post I downvoted is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247608/162011)

Answer (score 3):

This is a site wide feature request and such should be asked on Meta. Se. That said, I'm sure it's a duplicate feature request and has been requested multiple times. Best option in the mean time is to favorite it and check your favorites from time to time. It will update when a favorite is updated.

Comment: If am voting let say 20 posts then favoriting is not worthwhile.

Comment: When in asked this feature I am considering this Movies only as I felt need here only. Why it has to site wide feature.

Comment: Because it's about adding new feature and for request, you have to go to Mother Meta. There is actually no such feature and as cde said has been declined earlier too; if you have noticed the present version doesn't deserve the downvote, then just undo the downvote when you notice the post.

Comment: @panther because that's a major change to the base code of the entire network, and not something done piecemeal to individual sites. All M&TV is,  is a skin over the base code on a separate database.

Comment: @cde Understood now ,Intially seeing some differences in sites like options present in offtopic list. I thought we can add feature in single site. Thanks for clearing things to me

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I know this in not present now. Yes , when I notice , I do undo the votes and sometimes change. I just wanted if we could had some kind of notification anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get these notifications automatically, but you can manually, by using the **follow** feature under the relevant post. It will alert you to significant edits, answers, and comments.

You can also use the icon under the downvote icon, **Saves** (previously called *bookmarks* and *favorites*), to store a list of the posts you've downvoted. This will allow you some sorting features, including by most recent activity. This feature does not produce notifications.

Comment: Or bookmark it in your browser ;-)

Comment: There's no way to see which ones had updates with browser bookmarks.

Comment: You can see the edit dates below the questions and answers.